ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1 while inserting data using record in pgplsql
I am trying to migrate data from one table to another in postgresql via record but it throws error when null values in insert statement
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...s Promo",,\<ht...                                                                                                                      
QUERY:  insert into site_target values (100001,"2024-07-10 17:45:16.785991+00","2024-07-10 17:45:16.786007+00",100001,,1,1,0,"Monday to Friday 10AM-6PM",,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,,,,) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function data_movement_ref4(character varying,character varying,timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone) line 29 at EXECUTE SQL state: 42601

    create or replace procedure data_movement_ref4(source_table  in varchar, target_table in varchar, p_minimum_date in timestamp, p_end_date in timestamp ) 
    language plpgsql 
    as $$ 
    declare lv_string character varying(3000);
    v_sql character varying(3000); 
    loop_rec record; rec1 record; 
    cnt int; 
    c_cursor refcursor;
    p_min_dt timestamp;
    p_end_dt timestamp;
    begin
    
    raise notice '%',p_minimum_date ;
    v_sql:='insert into '||target_table||' values ';
    open c_cursor for execute 'select * from '||source_table|| ';'; 
             loop
               fetch c_cursor into loop_rec;
               exit when not found;
               execute v_sql|| loop_rec;
               raise notice '%',loop_rec ;
               cnt := cnt+1;
                    if cnt = 10000 then
                    commit;
                    end if;
                 end loop;
    close c_cursor;
    end; 
    $$


Code full of exploits for SQL injection. Use format() or one of the other options to avoid this

Looping through rows is an extremely inefficient way to migrate data (is looping a requirement or just an approach you've chosen to copy the data?). What is the use case? Besides SQL injection risks, there are many other defects. A major defect is that calling COMMIT closes open cursors. Even if that weren't the case there would still be other issues, including: cnt is never initialized, cnt = 10000 should be cnt % 10000 = 0, unused parameters and variables, no COMMIT after the loop, and arbitrary size limits caused by using CHARACTER VARYING(3000) instead of TEXT.
